# Spin bordism group of classifying space $BG$ with a finite Abelian $G$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, spectral-sequences, cobordism

The spin bordism group for the classifying space $BG$ of group $G$ can be denoted as $\Omega^{Spin}_d(BG)$.

For example, $\Omega^{Spin}_d(pt)$ are computed by [Anderson-Brown-Peterson](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970690?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (D. W. Anderson, E. H. Brown, Jr. and F. P. Peterson, The
structure of the Spin cobordism ring, Ann. of Math. 86, 271-298
(1967).).

Below we denote the finite cyclcic group of order $n$ as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_n$.

If we take $BG=pt$, one get

$\Omega^{Spin}_1(pt)=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\Omega^{Spin}_2(pt)=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\Omega^{Spin}_3(pt)=0$, $\Omega^{Spin}_4(pt)=\mathbb{Z}$

If we take $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$, we get,

$\Omega^{Spin}_1(B\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2^2$, $\Omega^{Spin}_2(B\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2^2$, $\Omega^{Spin}_3(B\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_8$, $\Omega^{Spin}_4(B\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}$

> Here are my questions, if we take $G=(\mathbb{Z}_2)^2$, or $G=(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$, $G=(\mathbb{Z}_2)^4$, what are the answers for the following:
>
> $$\Omega^{Spin}_1(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^2)=?, \Omega^{Spin}_2(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^2)=?, \Omega^{Spin}_3(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^2)=?, \Omega^{Spin}_4(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^2)=?$$
>
> $$\Omega^{Spin}_1(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3)=?, \Omega^{Spin}_2(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3)=?, \Omega^{Spin}_3(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3)=?, \Omega^{Spin}_4(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3)=?$$
>
> $$\Omega^{Spin}_1(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^4)=?, \Omega^{Spin}_2(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^4)=?, \Omega^{Spin}_3(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^4)=?, \Omega^{Spin}_4(B(\mathbb{Z}_2)^4)=?$$

P.S. Part of bordism group data may overlap with the group (co)homology data $H_d[G,\mathbb{Z}]$ or $H_d[G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}]$, $H^d[G,\mathbb{Z}]$ or $H^d[G,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}]$. Fortunately, [a Ref here in SUPPLEMENTAL MATERIAL](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.031601) shows the useful data in a table:

[image]

Any partial answers and any Refs are welcome.

Comment: Can you include what Atiyah-Hirzebruch gives you so far?

Comment: Thanks for the nice comment. There should be some recursion relation for the spin bordism group, here of the product of cyclic group. But I could not see it very easily.

Comment: Other G will nicely clear up on this page, but I suppose that is maximally unhelpful.

Comment: AHusain is right, the standard method would be to use the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence. The input on the $E^2$-page will be the homology (either mod 2 or integral, in these low dimensions) of these groups $G$. Since they are elementary abelian 2-groups, their homology should be easy to look up or calculate.

Answer (score 8):

The paper of Anderson, Brown and Peterson also shows that the localisation of the spectrum $MSpin$ splits as a wedge of suspensions of the real connective $K$-theory spectrum $kO$ and various closely related spectra.  It is also a theorem of Hopkins and Hovey that $KO_*(X)=KO_*\otimes_{MSpin_*}MSpin_*(X)$.  This shows that the calculation of the groups $\Omega^{spin}_*(BG)=MSpin_*(BG)$ is very closely related to the calculation of the groups $kO_*(BG)$ and $KO_*(BG)$.  Greenlees, Bruner and various collaborators have written extensively about this kind of question.  However, the answers are often very complicated.